# putting data from a LinkedBlockingQueue<> to an array not of type object

Tags: java, exception, casting, classcastexception, toarray

I am trying to do copy from a LinkedBlockingQueue to a dataStuff[] data array using .toArray() but I am getting an Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LdataStuff;
    at Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

with the following code

```
public static BlockingQueue<dataStuff> recurseFragments = new LinkedBlockingQueue<dataStuff>();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        dataStuff[] data = (dataStuff[]) recurseFragments.toArray();
    }
```

I understand that its putting the recurseFragments into an object[] before it spits it into the array but why is it that casting does not work and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [other toArray method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29)

```
dataStuff[] data = recurseFragments.toArray(new datastuff[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dataStuff[] data = recurseFragments.toArray(new dataStuff[0])
```

Using this signature of toArray you can get the correct type of return.

Comment: Thanks this worked but I accepted the answer that was posted first

Answer (score 1):

Because `toArray()` returns an `Object[]`

```
Object[] toArray();
```

So , you should use  `toArray(T[] a)` instead.

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

Use it this way:

```
recurseFragments.toArray(new datastuff[0]);
```